# hls.js - how to subscribe to any event

Tags: javascript, video, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

First time I play a playlist, I keep getting **bufferStalledError**.

I can detect this error, however, if I resolve this error **then a jump or skip** in the video play back occurs and it stops occurring.

However, if i ignore it then **it will play** without a noticable interruption **and the video keeps playing**. But this error will **continue to be raised** but without any noticable issues.

However, at times, the same error will **result in an overflow** and hls.js won't be able to recover automatically, and no further errors are reported after such a failure than the last **bufferStalled error**.

I have to restart the video through **destroy and attach** again resuming the play functionality hls.js is unable to do automatically or **through recoverMediaErrors()**.

The only problem is that I am unable to subscribe to an event that says that the video is playing, or stuck. After a bufferStalledMediaError hls.js will recover it automatically without a glitch, but sometimes it fails to do so. In both cases **no more errors are reported**.

But is there maybe another event reported that says it is playing that is not an error report?

Is there an hls.on(Hls.Events.ALL, ... )  event ?

What about setting up a **TimeLineController**? It's not documented.

Reference:
https://github.com/dailymotion/hls.js/blob/master/API.md

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there is a built in way to listen to all events, but you could always just subscribe to every event:

```
Object.keys(Hls.Events).forEach(function (e) {
    _hlsInstance.on(Hls.Events[e], console.info.bind(console));
});
```